# maven pom xml variables

Tags: java, maven

When setting a dependency. Let's assume the following

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Where does the

```
${plugin.testrunner.version}
```

variable get initialized? Is there a properties file or where does it gets it value?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should be intialised in a properties section, at the same level as your dependencies section, eg

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.0</plugin.testrunner.version>
    </properties>
...
    <dependencies>
...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you have a multi project application with a parent pom.xml it's common to put all your properties in there so they can be used by all of the individual poms.

Comment: It can also be set on command line with `-Dplugin.testrunner.version=<value>` syntax